# Div with height 0px so not showing background img

Tags: html, css, height

I have some div tags in my html code inside the body tag, like these:

```
<div class="landing">
<div class="home-wrap">
    <div class="home-inner">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want a background image inside the div tag with the home-inner class,
so in my CSS code I have something like this:

```
.home-inner {
background-image: url(../img/bg.jpg);
}
```

But when I test it, all my div tags have zero height, therefore the background image is not visible.
I have read that it has something to do with overflow, parents and children but I don't quite understand.

I am a beginner at this, so I appreciate your help in advance, greetings from Argentina.

--- EDIT ---

I need the image to be the background in all the height and width without scrolling,and keep it responsive but it still doesn't work.

I add a screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: just give a height to the div

Comment: `.home-inner{ width:250px; height:250px; background:url(../img/bg.jpg); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a height and width to `.home-inner` and make sure that your url has quotations `''` surrounding your image path. You can also customize the background-image using `background` properties.

```
.home-inner {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Greetings from Canada!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the picture is displayed in the upper left corner in a small size, don't know why.

Comment: The units for height and width are in fixed units ```px```, you can change them to be in responsive units ```vw``` for the width and ```vh``` for the height. Try setting ```width: 100vw``` and ```height: 100vh```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.home-inner {
background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
}
```

intead of

```
.home-inner {
background-image: url(../img/bg.jpg);
}
```

Note those qoutes.

Comment: I forgot that detail, but it still didn't work, thanks anyway!

Comment: The height and width of the image will not change if you use it as `background-image` i.e., The height and width of the image will remain the same as it it saved in your pc.      If you want it to be respnsive than you will have to use it in a `img` element.

Answer (score 1):

Since your div is empty it doesn't have a height so if u add this in your CSS the image will be shown in that div :

```
.home-inner {
   height:300px;
   background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
}
```

This will work!

Comment: It works but I don't get the result I need, thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: Glad it worked ! If u want the image to be covered use width:100%; in the css .home-inner.